# If eggs were left out of the fridge a few hours can they still be used as long as they are cooked thoroughy?

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I don't usually have food delivered. However due to circumstances my eggs were delivered to my home and I have no idea how long they were sitting in the car as the driver had multiple stops I assume.

It was somewhere between one and three hours I assume. The FDA says 2 hours out of the fridge tops. If it turns out it was three hours then as long as they are thoroughly cooked are they safe to eat?

Comment: Hi, you might want to read our tag-info on food safety, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.

Comment: @rumtscho . Yes that answers my question spot on.